# Why didn't Hundred Eyes assassinate Jia Sidao in their first encounter?

Tags: plot-explanation, marco-polo

In Netflix's Marco Polo, Hundred Eyes is sent to assassinate the Song chancellor Jia Sidao. He finds his target already in a duel with the new chancellor to be who is killed then a fight ensues between him and Sidao. Hundred Eyes is surprised to find Sidao a formidable opponent with his Mantis Kung Fu but he is not bested (in the finale we see Sidao also knows the Mantis moves). Guards arrive and the scene ends.

I don't get why he didn't continue with his mission.

Answer (score 1):

**It would have been too risky.**

Hundred Eyes' mission was to assassinate Jia Sidao who resides inside the Imperial Palace. After Jia escaped from the fight with Hundred Eyes, Hundred Eyes probably thought it would be too risky to run after Jia inside the Imperial Palace as he would have to fight skilled Imperial Guards.

Answer (score -1):

It's just bad writing.  The writer setup a situation he couldn't resolve so they left it a "mystery" aka 'author's convenience.'  There is no way that a political figure like the chancellor would have the fighting skills of a monk who has found 'emptiness.'   Bad writing.